# having trouble mail server to apple mac

Tags: outlook, mac, outlook-web-app, apple, outlook-2013

I'm having trouble after adding an account to an Apple Mac. The email server is ours and we host the emails of the customer.

After changing the settings to point to our mail server and adding the profile to the account in Outlook 2013, the customer can receive email but not send them! It works fine from the online Exchange OWA, but when in Outlook 2013 on the Mac it displays this error:

> The user account which was used to submit this request does not have the right to send mail on behalf of the specified sending account

Is this a problem with smtp? If I'm right, I don't think smtp outgoing server is available to change for an Exchange account? I may be wrong, I'm new at setting up on Macs so please be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Send on Behalf is an Exchange permission used in delegation scenarios.

If OWA works as expected, I would assume the Outlook:Mac profile was setup incorrectly. Ideally, a user should input their mail address in the wizard and Autodiscover would take care of setup.

---

Edit:

Outlook:Mac client uses Exchange Web Services (EWS) extensively (exclusively?). You may need to check your Exchange CAS configuration to ensure nothing is blocking this.